# Spark Counter : Main method/ extends App gives different output for same application, Why it is so?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have a file which is having some missing data, So I am trying to identify the missing record count by using counter variable.

```
File: data-error.csv                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
123,200,Abc
124,300,xyz
125,4,
126,abd
127,400,abc1
```

This file contains ***Total No Records= 5 and Missing Record = 2***

> Program By extending App trait : output **5 2**

```
object CountersTest extends App{
  val conf=new SparkConf().setAppName("CounterTest").setMaster("local")
  val sc=new SparkContext(conf)

  val fileRDD=sc.textFile("data-error.csv")
  var missingRecords=0

  val rdd1=fileRDD.map(rec=>{
    val parseResult=RecordParser.parse(rec)
    if(parseResult.isLeft) missingRecords+=1
    rec
  })
  println(rdd1.count())
  println(missingRecords)
}
```

> Program By using main method : output **5 0**

```
object CounterWithMain {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val conf=new SparkConf().setAppName("CounterTest").setMaster("local")
    val sc=new SparkContext(conf)

    val fileRDD=sc.textFile("data-error.csv")
    var missingRecords=0

    val rdd1=fileRDD.map(rec=>{
      val parseResult=RecordParser.parse(rec)
      if(parseResult.isLeft) missingRecords+=1
      rec
    })
    println(rdd1.count())                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    println(missingRecords)
  }
}
```

Why this same application is giving different output ? Please help me out on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That question returns NullpointerException and mine is giving answer. and I didn't use brodcast variable. So I think both are different question. @stefanobaghino

Comment: As stated in the official documentation https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html#self-contained-applications **Note that applications should define a main() method instead of extending scala.App. Subclasses of scala.App may not work correctly.**

Comment: Here is the caveats, App is implemented using the DelayedInit functionality, which means that fields of the object will not have been initialized before the main method has been executed.

Comment: So when you create a Spark Application extending App, this will result in delayed initialization and thus setting null values within closures, which explains the different results.

Comment: Thank you so Much!. @eliasah .